# Question about SQL Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables in a MySQL DB

Table 1 has the following fields

```
Name of Table: SupervisorTable 
supervisorid (autoinc, bigint) 
employeeid (bigint) //same as User.userid
supervisorname

Name of Table: User 
userid (autoinc, bigint) 
userFullName (string) 
supervisorid (bigint) 
divisionid (bigint)

Name of Table: DivisionTable 
divisionid(autoinc, bigint) 
divisionname (string)
```

I want to be able to determine which department a supervisor works in and my output should be
supervisor name and the division name.  My latest attempt:

```
SELECT supervisortable.supervisorname,
       divisiontable.divisionname 
  FROM supervisortable, 
       user, 
       divisiontable 
 WHERE supervisortable.employeeid = user.userid;
```

This gave every combination of supervisor name with every department:

```
supervisorname  divisionname
----------------------------
UserA           Department1
UserB           Department1
UserA           Department2
...
UserB           DepartmentN
```

Comment: @Cocoa Dev: What have you tried?

Comment: What do you have so far?  It looks like you have a many to many.  And a duplicate field.  Is every supervisor also a user?

Comment: Would the supervisor belong to the division that their user record is associated with?  or is the supervisor assigned to the division that their direct reports are in?

Comment: Every supervisor is also a user. The SupervisorTable.employeeid is the same number as User.userid (autoinc, bigint, primary)

Comment: Ok. And what about SupervisorTable.supervisorname?  Is that the same as userFullName?

Comment: You're missing a join on divisiontable.  See some of the comments below.

Comment: Fixed the problem. There was an issue with the data. Thats why it was giving us an empty set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are wanting a query that finds all supervisors and list the desired output in your OP then this will do it:

```
SELECT S.supervisorname,
       D.divisionname
  FROM SuperisorTable S
  JOIN User U ON S.employeeid= U.supervisorid
  JOIN DivisionTable D ON U.divisionid = D.divisionid
```

Because without criteria, you're getting a cartesian product (that's bad, unless you *really* want that).

Comment: how come its giving me an empty set?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.supervisorname, d.divisionname
FROM DivisionTable d, SupervisorTable s, User u
WHERE d.divisionid =  u.divisionid
AND s.supervisorid = u.supervisorid
AND s.employeeid = u.userid
```

Comment: when I run it, I get empty set back. I have two supervisors and 3 employees (each supervisor is also an employee). the s.employeeid is the same as u.userid (i modified the above query to match the column names)

Answer (score 0):

I'f I'm understanding your data structure correctly:

```
SELECT 
  S.supervisorname,        
  D.divisionname 
FROM SuperisorTable S  
INNER JOIN Users U ON S.employeeid = U.userid  
INNER JOIN DivisionTable D ON U.divisionid = D.divisionid
```